# Why is my question getting voted down?

Tags: discussion

I'm a long-time user of WP StackExchange - and I'm legitimately curious why my question is getting voted down with no comments indicating why. Did I not provide enough information? Perhaps I didn't explain my particular problem well enough so people think the answer is trivial (When I'm pretty sure it's not)? Please, let me know!

[Widget Admin - Form Submit Event?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198689/widget-admin-form-submit-event/198898)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Your question is technically perfectly on topic and interesting, but the form (no pun intended :) of it has some issues:

1. It's overly laconic, questions that are barely two sentences people are *used to* regard as low quality
2. It presumes the knowledge of making the widget process, making harder for anyone who hadn't done this recently (or ever) to take a quick look
3. It ambiguous, did you mean save button of any widget? Your widget? What about if there is more than one instance of your widget?
4. Literally you are asking for *"code"*, not a *knowledge/solution*. Another thing that triggers knee–jerk low quality reaction.

Comment: Thanks Rarst. Those make sense. Maybe I should have given a bit more background (your #2) and been a bit more specific. I'll see if I can edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I didn't downvote but it seem your question is more to do with jQuery then WordPress. If I misunderstood, perhaps rephrasing it will help.

Sometime sharing code helps better understanding the problem then long explanation. It also shows you did tried to solve your problem before you started a thread.

It is a common problem in SE network some people will downvote but will never comment to point it out but looking at the Q with 4 downvotes there should be at least one comment explaining downvotes.

Comment: I want to note that while "explaining" downvotes _seems_ logical, it is empirical fact that plenty people react badly to downvotes and more so to "explanation". There is a point to downvotes being anonymous (well, mods have some visibility into it), using them silently is perfectly fine. If OP is interested in improving the Q they have other means to (like this thread).

Comment: Thanks - yes I think it was probably a mistake mentioning jQuery - I should've stuck with "javascript event" instead of mentioning the word "jquery" which is usually associated with low quality questions.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would like to start of by saying that apart from what have been noted in the other answers, I would like to add that, being a member with reputation of more than 2K! you should by now know how to ask a proper question.

I'm not trying to be rude or offend you, and if it feels that way, I would really like to take the opportunity now and say that I'm sorry and also tell you that I did not intent any harm. :-)

To come back to the point, there is just nothing concrete in your question to go on. Reading the comments to the answers given, you have left out important information as well, which in turn fueled some negative interest in your question. Worst of all, you still have not even taken the time to add the extra **VERY IMPORTANT** info in your question.

In my opinion it is still a very low quality question which should have been closed for something like unclear or too broad. Adding a bounty on top of such a question does not make it more acceptable as a question, it still remains low quality.

Most users, and that includes me, downvote without commenting (*I however still try to leave comments, specially on answers from time to time*). The big reasons for me behind this is

- Revenge voting to which I have been a victim of a couple times. I'm really really not in the mood for someone else's childishness. I have always removed my downvotes with proper edits, that is the whole concept behind this.
- Users that swear and blatantly calling one names and just plain rudeness. This almost always turns into a fight. We all have a breaking point, and if someone goes on and on, I eventually end up being really rude and then getting warned by the mods. So I totally avoid that now.
- There are a basic guide on all SE sites which everyone can use as a guide on how to ask a proper well received question. I still feel that most users simply neglet that or simply takes a chance and hope that someone will still do their job for them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think it is a specific question - asking a particular question about a particular place in the WordPress dev stack. I'm not sure how I could be more specific. I did leave out the "I don't want to just have the click event - I want it to call the event if the user clicks or presses enter" - I agree with you there that I could have added that, but that does not make the question broad, or unclear.

Comment: PS - just added http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/198689/4

Comment: Also, I don't think my question falls into any of your final three bullet points ... so I'm not quite sure why you added that to your answer. Could you please explain if my original question falls into one of those categories?

Comment: The three bullet points merely points out why people downvote without leaving comments, that answers your question as to why people downvote without leaving comments